# Which, if any, planets and characters are known during the space hop scene?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

During the 700 space hops scene, where we see Rocket and crew passing over a number of planets, some of them struck me as possible Easter eggs or references to other known properties.

In this scene we see Stan Lee's cameo, for instance. But there were other planets, such as one with two blue-looking gladiator-like aliens who paused their fight to look up at the spaceship jumping through the area.

The Stan Lee scene is the only one I can personally identify, and it also had the longest screen time. Others happened so quickly that I don't recall the details.

Do we know, or can we make an educated guess based on commentary and/or comic books, what these other planets or who these other characters are?

Comment: Related: [What universes do Rocket and Yondu jump through?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/72902/44293)

Comment: @Edlothiad Huh, funny. I've wanted to ask this since I saw the movie, but didn't get to it, and an _earlier_ [movies.se] question reminded me. Funny that we ended up posting around the same time.

Answer (score 10):

These are the easter eggs for that particular scene:

1. [The two gladiator-like aliens are called **Kronans**](http://screenrant.com/guardians-galaxy-2-easter-eggs/). Kronans are an ancient race of rock-like humanoids. In Thor 2, one Kronan warrior was a member of the Marauders, and was present during the battle against the Asgardians.
2. Stan Lee's cameo of having a chat with a group of Watchers is a nod towards a popular fan theory that Lee is in fact not playing dozens of different characters in his Marvel films cameos, but one single being traversing space and time, the most prominent suggestion being **Uatu the Watcher.**
3. The hexagon-shaped warp holes in the hyperspace jump scene resembles the **Stargate** network of the Shi'ar and Xandar in the Marvel Comics. These are devices that stabilize wormholes allowing intergalactic transportation around the universe.

The other planets that were shown in the scene are not that familiar but I will try to post more if I find out more information.

Comment: The warriors were Korg's people? I forget that Thor 2 made them more gray than brown compared to the comics. Now that you've given me that info I've been able to find articles showing that.

Comment: On 2: Hopefully it's not his last appearance. Maybe we can even get a solid answer on it, in-universe.